# Avoid duplicate increment in SERIAL column in mutiple machines

Tags: postgresql, database-design, auto-increment

Now I installed Postgres on single machine and created a table with `serial` column. This column auto increments whenever a new row will insert. If I install Postgres on another machine for distributed computing and create same table with `serial` column, `serial` column starts from 1? Or can I set minimum value for the column(maximum value of 1st machine + 1)?

Answer (score 4):

By default, `SERIAL` creates a `SEQUENCE` that begins with one.

If you want, you can modify the sequence so each machine has a distinct start value and all sequences have an offset after table creation. For examples, `ALTER SEQUENCE the_sequence_name START WITH 2 INCREMENT BY 10`. Give each machine has a different `START WITH` value and make sure they all have the *same* `INCREMENT BY`. That way each machine is guaranteed to get unique IDs.

You may want to use a `bigint` key column if you do this, and to allocate a large offset like `INCREMENT BY 1000`. That way you won't be in pain when you have to add machine #11.

Another option is to use `uuid` primary keys.

Comment: Consider my answer regarding `START` vs. `RESTART`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the **`START`** clause in [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html) only sets the default starting value. It does **not** change the current value of the sequence, that's a common misconception.

If you use the clause in the [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html) statement, the sequence is initialized with the `START` value it and it woks as expected: the first call with `nextval()` will return `7` here:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE foo_seq START WITH 7 INCREMENT BY 16;
```

However, if you run `ALTER SEQUENCE`, the sequence has already been initialized to some other value (1 by default) and you **need** to add a **`RESTART`** clause to actually reset the sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE foo_seq START WITH 7 INCREMENT BY 16 RESTART;
```

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html)

> ***restart***
>
> The optional clause `RESTART [ WITH restart ]` changes the current value of the sequence. This is equivalent to calling the `setval`
>   function with `is_called = false`: the specified value will be returned
>   by the next call of `nextval`. Writing `RESTART` with no restart value is
>   equivalent to supplying the start value that was recorded by `CREATE`
>   `SEQUENCE` or last set by `ALTER SEQUENCE START WITH`.

That's what you need when you alter the sequence created implicitly for a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column.
That's also what you actually need for your question:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE foo_seq RESTART WITH max_of_other_tbl;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE** demonstrating the variants.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1434)

Comment: I would choose a power of two as increment. That would cause (hypothetical) wrap-around to only have effect on the local installation, instead of colliding with the peers.

Comment: @wildplasser: Valid consideration. No cost, some gain. I adapted my example accordingly.

Comment: I have yet to experience my first wrap-around serial. But I would not like it to be a multi-installation issue (remember the Oracle High-watermark thing ... ?)